# C++ CLR System::Diagnostics::Process, Redirect Output After Process has Started?

Tags: c++, process, clr, system.diagnostics

I'm using [System::Diagnostics::Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)'s GetProcessesByName to check and see if a certain process is running on the machine. I want to be able to redirect the process it find's output to a console in my CLR project. How do I do that when it (the process found) is already running?

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the processes [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event.

Comment: This requires you to have created the process with redirection, which is not the case here.